# how to unit test a function that calls a service function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've a basic function in a controller that calls out a service and was wondering how to go about testing this function.

### controller

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, loginService) {  
    $scope.login = function() {
        loginService.login($scope);
    }
});
```

### service

```
app.factory('loginService', function(parserService, $location, $http {
    return {
        login : function(scope) {
        parserService.get(function(data) {
            if (scope.username === data.username
                    && scope.password === data.password) {
                authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
                authentication.user = data.fullname;
                authentication.userImg = data.imgUrl;
                $location.url("/homepage");
            } else {
                scope.loginError = "Invalid login";
            }
        })
      }
    }
});
```

### unit test so far

```
it('should call loginservice and check credentials', inject(function($rootScope,
        $controller, loginService) {
    //create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $scope.login = function (){};
    spyOn($scope, "login");

    ctrl = $controller('loginCtrl', {
        $scope : $scope,
        loginService : loginService
    });

    $scope.username = 'admin';
    $scope.password = 'a';
    expected($scope.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith(loginService.login($scope);
            ///Some logic here to return successful login with give credentials/ or error `invalid login` 
}));
});
```

Now how do I unit test this login service, do I need to modify my loginService.login() function login in order to be tested etc. Not sure how its done!!!

Comment: It seems you just need to mock an HTTP response and the $location service and then verify values that `$location.url` has been called with the proper argument or the `$scope.loginError` has been properly set. (I am not sure where `authentication comes from.)

Comment: authentication is just a boolean to verify if it's set to true then that means user is loggedin otherwise its not logged in. can you provide a demo/ or code snippet how can tht be done because i'm getting a failure:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing a service that calls other services, you can usually mock those other services (or only the ones needed) and verify that the expected functions where called and the appropriate arguments where passed.

When `$http` or `$resource` are involved (which rely on `$httpBackend`) you can mock responses (or just verify certain endpoints where hit).

---

There is not enough info in your question regarding how `$http`, `parseService` or `authenticate` are used, but from what I can infer you could spy on `$locations`'s `url` method or verify that `$scope.loginError` has been properly set.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/7fwsL/)**.